# Structures in c

Tags: c

I am getting errors for the below program.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>

struct s 
{
  char *st;
  struct s *sp; 
};

struct s *p1,*p2;
swap(p1,p2);

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct s *p[3];
    static struct s a[]={
        {"abc",a+1},{"def",a+2},{"ghi",a}
    };
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
     p[i]=a[i].sp;
    }
    swap(*p,a);
    printf("%s %s %s\n",p[0]->st,(*p)->st,(*p)->sp->st);
    return 0;
}

swap(p1,p2)
{
    char *temp;
    temp = p1->st;
    p1->st = p2->st;
    p2->st = temp;
}
```

How to make this program working.Even if we didnt put int before swap I hope it will by default take it as int .

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> error C2078: too many initializers
>
> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 's *' to 'int'
>           There is no context in which this conversion is possible
>
> error C2450: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
>
> error C2456:'swap' : function-style

Comment: Can you please provide the line numbers for the errors? Also I think that some text might have been lost in the error messages. I reformatted, but it still looks a bit odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
void swap(struct s *p1, struct s *p2);

void swap(struct s *p1, struct s *p2)
{
    char *temp;
    temp = p1->st;
    p1->st = p2->st;
    p2->st = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `swap` function doesn't return anything. In C, this should be marked with the `void` keyword (see @Dave's comment that it is indeed allowed, it looks though as you are compiling with a C++ compiler where it is not allowed). You must also specify the types of `p1` and `p2`:

```
void swap(struct s *p1, struct s *p2);
```

and

```
void swap(struct s *p1, struct s *p2)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Technically, it doesn't *have* to. functions without return types default to `int`, and `int` functions don't *have* to have a return statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
swap(p1,p2)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

This is wrong. You need to specify what are the types of `p1,p2` as a part of function definition. Even the same with the forward declaration of `swap` function. And also mention it's return type.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has many mistakes... some of them I can't correct since I couldn't get what is supposed to be the intended behavior...

First thing first, you do not need to globally declare the parameters `struct s *p1,*p2` of a function you want to define. Second, a function prototype must include the types of the parameters in question, as well as a return type (in your case void). Third thing, the first pamater of the swap function is a pointer to your struct, therefore you need to pass the first element (a pointer to a `s struct) of the`p` array.

The following compiles and does not seg faults, even if I think its behavior is not the one you would expect.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s {
    char *st;
    struct s *sp; 
};

void swap(struct s *ptr1, struct s *ptr2);

int main() {
    int i;
    struct s *p[3];

    static struct s a[]={ {"abc",a+1}, {"def",a+2}, {"ghi",a} };
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        p[i] = a[i].sp;
    }
    swap(p[0], a);
    printf("%s %s %s\n",p[0]->st,(*p)->st,(*p)->sp->st);
    return 0;
}

void swap(struct s *ptr1, struct s *ptr2) {
    char *temp;
    temp = ptr1->st;
    ptr1->st = ptr2->st;
    ptr2->st = temp;
}
```